# Samba 4.8 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, samba

I have compiled from source `samba 4.8` on Ubuntu xenial, but I can't start it.

Following the samba.org instructions I got to the point where in `/usr/local/samba/sbin` and `/usr/local/samba/bin` I have the executables, and before I uninstalled the old `4.3` version on my pc I saved the `/etc/init.d/smbd` file in order to get it to work. But even after changing the location of the binaries in the init.d file it still doesn't work.

if I run /etc/init.d/smbd start this is what I get

```
[....] Starting smbd (via systemctl): smbd.serviceJob for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
failed!
```

This is the output for journalctl -xe

```
-- i servizi attivati sono in fase di completamento.
-- 
-- L'avvio del kernel ha richiesto KERNEL_USEC microsecondi.
-- 
-- L'avvio del disco RAM ha richiesto INITRD_USEC microsecondi.
-- 
-- L'avvio dello userspace ha richiesto 24776 microsecondi.
mar 26 23:18:12 apollo systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1001.
-- Subject: L'unità user@1001.service termina la fase di avvio
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- L'unità user@1001.service ha terminato la fase di avvio.
-- 
-- La fase di avvio è done.
mar 26 23:18:30 apollo sudo[11809]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
mar 26 23:18:46 apollo sudo[11913]: francesco : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/francesco ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/nano /lib/systemd/system/smbd.service
mar 26 23:18:46 apollo sudo[11913]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by francesco(uid=0)
mar 26 23:19:03 apollo sudo[11913]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
mar 26 23:19:06 apollo sudo[11929]: francesco : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/francesco ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/etc/init.d/smbd start
mar 26 23:19:06 apollo sudo[11929]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by francesco(uid=0)
mar 26 23:19:06 apollo systemd[1]: Starting Samba SMB/CIFS server...
-- Subject: L'unità smbd.service inizia la fase di avvio
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- L'unità smbd.service ha iniziato la fase di avvio.
mar 26 23:19:06 apollo systemd[1]: smbd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
mar 26 23:19:06 apollo systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba SMB/CIFS server.
-- Subject: L'unità smbd.service è fallita
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- L'unità smbd.service è fallita.
-- 
-- Il risultato è failed.
mar 26 23:19:06 apollo systemd[1]: smbd.service: Unit entered failed state.
mar 26 23:19:06 apollo systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
mar 26 23:19:06 apollo sudo[11929]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Sorry for Italian messages, but the important ones are English.

This is the init.d script

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          smbd
# Required-Start:    $network $local_fs $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $network $local_fs $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Should-Start:      slapd cups
# Should-Stop:       slapd cups
# Short-Description: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)
### END INIT INFO


PIDDIR=/var/run/samba
SMBDPID=$PIDDIR/smbd.pid

# clear conflicting settings from the environment
unset TMPDIR

# See if the daemons are there
test -x /usr/local/samba/sbin/smbd || exit 0

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

case $1 in
    start)
        if init_is_upstart; then
            exit 1
        fi
        SERVER_ROLE=`samba-tool testparm --parameter-name="server role"  2>/dev/null | tail -1`
        if [ "$SERVER_ROLE" = "active directory domain controller" ]; then
            exit 0
        fi

        log_daemon_msg "Starting SMB/CIFS daemon" smbd
        # Make sure we have our PIDDIR, even if it's on a tmpfs
        install -o root -g root -m 755 -d $PIDDIR

        if ! start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --exec /usr/local/samba/sbin/smbd -- -D; then
            log_end_msg 1
            exit 1
        fi

        log_end_msg 0
        ;;
    stop)
        if init_is_upstart; then
            exit 0
        fi

        log_daemon_msg "Stopping SMB/CIFS daemon" smbd

        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile $SMBDPID
        # Wait a little and remove stale PID file
        sleep 1
        if [ -f $SMBDPID ] && ! ps h `cat $SMBDPID` > /dev/null
        then
            # Stale PID file, remove it (should be removed by
            # smbd itself IMHO).
            rm -f $SMBDPID
        fi

        log_end_msg 0

        ;;
    reload)
        log_daemon_msg "Reloading /etc/samba/smb.conf" smbd

        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --signal HUP --pidfile $SMBDPID

        log_end_msg 0
        ;;
    restart|force-reload)
        if init_is_upstart; then
            exit 1
        fi
        $0 stop
        sleep 1
        $0 start
        ;;
        status)
        status_of_proc -p $SMBDPID /usr/local/samba/sbin/smbd smbd
        exit $?
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/smbd {start|stop|reload|restart|force-reload|status}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

And this is the smbd.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Samba SMB/CIFS server
After=network.target nmbd.service winbindd.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/samba/sbin/smbd -D
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Are the PIDDIR and SMBPID important?

Even if I run `sudo /usr/local/samba/sbin/smbd -D` I still get nothing, no error and no smb showing up in `ps aux | grep smb`

Comment: Why did you compile from source? There is a package `samba`. There is also a tutorial on how to install samba https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-and-configure-samba#0

Comment: Because I need 4.8 not 4.3 which is the version that is installed with sudo apt-get install samba. I looked for a precompiled package or a ppa that contained the version I need but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of testing, mainly running `sudo smbd -FS` to show the output as stdout, I found that the executable located in `/usr/local/samba/sbin` isn't loading the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file but the `/usr/local/samba/etc/smb.conf`. After copying the default one in the expected location everything started working properly.

It was probably a configuration flag I missed. Hope it helps somebody else with the same issue.

Moreover, since the install from source process doesn't do it, I had to add the `smb.service` in `/etc/avahi/services/` folder to be advertised correctly.

I am still working on how to have it appear in network on Windows, but connecting with \ip.add.re.ss it works, and on Mac it shows correctly.